# Interval of a timer - from integer to float/double - Delphi

Tags: delphi, timer, integer, double, intervals

Is there a way to work around the Limits of the Ttimer's inteval so it can be preciser? for example instead of only integers like 1000ms , to use 1000.5ms . And if no, which component can I use instead which will give me preciser interval

Comment: Windows timer resolution is typically 15ms. I cannot make sense of your question at all.

Comment: like David already said, the timer event is not going to be fired at precisely 1000 ms every time, however I don't get why you need to sync your timer with the website...

Comment: Sorry Warren but I dont seem to understand whats so confusing When I put my timer interval to 1014ms then after an hour I check and see that the timer I have is being to early(fast) compared to their timer. And when my is 1015 After an hour I can see the difference which is now in seconds and my timer is being too late (slow)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. That's confusing for people who like things to make sense. For starters, what do you mean by "synchronize"? You mean, "guess and fire my timer when I think that guy is going to fire his timer?"

Comment: Unclear questions? Better call Saul!

Comment: I want that if we both start our timers and every time the timer interval is over (1000 milliseconds , so after 1 sec its over) then X will be +1 and at the end after 10 hours  I want my X and their X to be exactly the same

Comment: Impossible. You are aware of the principles of skew, jitter, drift, and latency right? Let's assume they aren't using an atomic clock, and are in fact, using the PC time-of-day clock.  Daily drift on that could be up to 30 seconds on some machines.

Comment: Well the problem is that even after 1 minute the difference is 1~sec even thought it was 0 at the begining which means after 1 hour the difference is 60 seconds and I though if i will change the interval that difference will be smaller and eventually disappear if I will get to the right number but since the interval is integer and preciser values wouldnt be integer I cant find the answear

Comment: Stop using timers to measure time. All that is guaranteed with a timer is that it will fire no sooner than the interval you specify. It could fire any time later.

Comment: well then how do you think I should measure time?

Comment: I fixed your question. You see now?

Comment: Yea thanks I guess thats what I meant :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to keep track of time to a reasonable degree of accuracy. However, the standard system timer cannot be used for that purpose.  All that the system timer guarantees is that it will fire *no sooner* than the interval which you specify. And you can get the message late if you are tardy in pumping your message queue. Quite simply, the system timer is  not designed to be used as a stopwatch and to attempt to do so is inappropriate.

Instead you need to use the high resolution performance counter which you can get hold of by calling [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx).

If you are using Delphi 2010 or later then you can use [`Diagnostics.TStopwatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Diagnostics.TStopwatch) which provides a very convenient wrapper to the high performance timer.

You can still use a system timer to give your app a regular tick or pulse, but make sure that you keep track of time with the high resolution timer.

Having said all of that, I'm not sure that you will ever be able to achieve what you are hoping to do. If you want to keep reasonably accurate time then what I say above is true. Trying to maintain lock-step synchronisation with code running on another machine somewhere remote over the net sounds pretty much intractable to me.

Comment: Okay and what if I told you that when 6 hours pass for the second timer BOTH of the timer reset to 6:00 and 6:00- but for example when the first reach 3:00 the second is only at 3:30 , so more accurate interval will eventually let me be precise enough to have the exact number of seconds as the second timer , eventually after more than 6 hours there will be a difference but all I need is it to be accurate for exactly 6 hours, so is there a way to make the interval more precise then integer number of miliseconds?

Comment: To answer that would just be to repeat myself. Stop using the system timer. Use a high res timer instead.

Comment: I just check and delphi doesnt recognize TStopwatch when I am trying to do somthing like watch:TStopwatch, even though I Have delphi 2010 . Is there a way to download it , compatible to 2010? because I didnt find .

Answer (score 0):

1) The TTimer class is not accurate enough for your task, period! (then again, neither would the web-site timer be, either)

2) If you increase the timer resolution using the TimeBeginPeriod() API call, this will get you closer, but still nowhere near close enough

3) If you adjust the TTimer interval each time based on a constant start time (and synchronised with the PC clock), you can average a set number of milliseconds for each time event compared to the PC clock

4) I don't know if the TTimer class handles 3) correctly, but I have a TTimer equivalent that does

5) To account for PC clock drift you will need to synchronise the PC clock periodically with an NTP server

6) I have a system that keeps the PC clock on a good machine to with +/- 5 milliseconds of a reference time permanently (I adjust every minute) and a timer with a resolution of +/- 2 milliseconds as long as the machine is not overloaded (Windows is not a real-time OS)

7) It took me a long time to get to this point - is this what you really need, or are you asking the wrong question?